# How to style Boostrap footer?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the Bootstrap temple for the sticky footer and I'm trying to style the unordered list that is inside, but can't get the list to be inline.

HTML:

```
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
      <p class="text-muted">
        <div class="bottom-list">
            <ul>
                <li>Prevajanje</li>
                <li>Lektura</li>
                <li>Sodni prevodi</li>
                <li>Tolmačenje</li>
            </ul>
      </div>
      </p>
   </div>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
.footer .container .text-muted .bottom-list {
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: Here is a fiddle => https://jsfiddle.net/L0hbsuoL/ and also have a look at this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp) for basics of inlining `li`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `list-inline` class.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="list-inline">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Source: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-lists

Answer (score 1):

The CSS rule you have specified applies to the `ul` element. To inline a list you should target the `li` elements within the `ul`. For example

```
.bottom-list>li {
     display: inline-block;
}
```

It is preferable to use predefined bootstrap classes though in this case `list-inline`.